# What do you take as the Particular Integral when is cancels out

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the second order ODE $\ddot{x} + \omega^2x = A\cos(\omega t)$ and when I try to solve the PI it cancels out to be just $0 = A\cos(\omega t)$.  What do I take for the PI?

Comment: You should have learned something about multiplying by powers of $t$ when the forcing is a homogeneous solution.

Comment: @Ian I've looked through my lecture notes many times and re-watched the lecture videos, however, I can't seem to find anything about it.  By multiplying by powers of t, do you mean take $t(pcos(\omega t) + qcos(\omega t))$?

Comment: @Holdaheck21 i miscalculated so i didn't realize the homogeneous solution had a cosine in it. If there is a matching function in the inhomogenous term (resonance) then you have to multiply by $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with hyperbolic/trigonometric functions we never just take one of them.
Always use them in pairs, that way you won't lose data.

$$f(t)=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t)$$

where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

[Particular Solutions for the Inhomogeneous term](https://www.efunda.com/math/ode/linearode_undeterminedcoeff.cfm)

If the homogenous solution has a similar term to the inhomogeneus one (resonance), you should multiply your 'testing' function by a $t$.

Comment: That actually won't help in this particular case anyway, because the sine will cancel out too.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I used $qcos(\omega t) + psin(\omega t)$ and when you double differentiate that and sub into the original statement it becomes $0 = Acos(\omega t)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\ddot{x} + \omega^2x = A\cos(\omega t)$$
For the particular solution try:
$$x_p=Ct\sin(\omega t)$$